# ffmpeg-next how can I enable multithreading on a decoder?

Tags: rust, ffmpeg

I'm using the rust crate `ffmpeg-next` to decode some video into individual frames for usage in another library. Problem is when I run my test it only seems to use a single core. I've tried modifying the threading configuration for my decoder as you can see below, but It doesn't seem to be do anything

```rs
        let context_decoder =
            ffmpeg_next::codec::context::Context::from_parameters(input_stream.parameters())?;
        let mut decoder = context_decoder.decoder().video()?;
        let mut threading_config = decoder.threading();
        threading_config.count = num_cpus::get();
        threading_config.kind = ThreadingType::Frame;

        decoder.set_threading(threading_config);
```